# Python socket with worker threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm playing with Python to understand basics of client-server and threading programming.

This is my main.py application:

```
from threading import Thread 
from Server import Server


    class Worker(object):

        def __init__(self, clients):
            #constructor
            self.clients = clients

        def start(self):
            while True:
                print("it work as expected!")
                conn, addr = self.clients.get()
                print( conn.recv(1024) )

    #create a instance of the server
    server = Server()

    #put on a new thread 
    def serverThreadCallback(server):
        server.start()

    def createWorkerCallback():
        worker = Worker(server.getClients())
        worker.start()


    #put the server on a new thread
    serverThread = Thread( target=serverThreadCallback, args=(server, )  )
    serverThread.daemon = True
    serverThread.start()

    '''
    workerThread = Thread(target=createWorkerCallback) 
    workerThread.daemon = True
    workerThread.start()
    '''
```

and this is my server.py

```
import socket
import queue


class Server(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.clients = queue.Queue() 

    def create(self):
        print("Creating server...")
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR , 1)
        self.socket = server

    def listen(self):
        print("Starting server...")
        self.socket.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 9002) )
        self.socket.listen(10)
        print("Server started. Listening on localhost port 9002")
        while(True): 
            #conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            self.clients.put(self.socket.accept())

    def start(self):
        self.create()
        self.listen()

    def getClients(self):
        return self.clients
```

When I try to start the server in that thread, the listening method
doesn't call. Something goes stuck in create() method from the server.

What I've did wrong?

Comment: `def start(self):` is a threading specific name, should not be replacing that.

Comment: I've replaced def start(self): with def startServer(self): and there are still the same problem. The code from listen method are not executed.

Comment: Add a `print()` for each line in `startServer`, see how far it comes to narrow things down for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are a couple of syntax errors on the coded you posted:

***main.py:***

**1)** Indentation starting from your `class` declaration is wrong

**2)** You should call `from server import Server` (note the module name is `server` - in lower case)

***server.py***

**3)** You should call `import Queue` (and not `import queue`)

**4)** Therefore the call to `self.clients = queue.Queue()` should become `self.clients = Queue.Queue()` (the module name is `Queue` with upper case `Q`)

Other than that, you have to add a `serverThread.join()` after `serverThread.start()`, otherwise the main thread finishes and the program terminates before your server thread has had the chance to start.

Finally, you might want to change the call to accept() inside the thread, such that it times out from time to time to handle Ctrl+C interrupts properly (otherwise you can only finish your program by killing it)

Comment: thanks for answer. If I want to wait for sockets message (using recv) I need to create a new thread for each client and put socket.recv() in a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
serverThread.daemon = True
```

Daemon threads are abruptly stopped when Python program exits.
Maybe the `listen()` method hasn't been called yet.